# Reacting to window variable?

Tags: javascript, mobx

So to check if there is internet connectivity, we can use `window.navigator.onLine` If *true*, it means internet is connected, *false* means internet is disconnected.

This is my attempt to automatically have MobX discover this and console log the respective message. It works on load when connected to the internet by logging `'internet connected'`, 
however,  as soon as I disconnect from the internet, it does not console log the respective message `'internet disconnected'`.

```
const { observable, reaction } = mobx;

class NetStore {    
  constructor() {
    if(window.navigator) {
        reaction(
          () => window.navigator.onLine,
          (value) => {
             value ? console.log('internet connected') 
                   : console.log('internet disconnected');
          },
          true // makes reaction fire immediately
        );
    }
  }
}

const store = new NetStore();
```

In short, I just want to use this store to detect whether there is an internet connection or not, so I can let the user know if there is no connection, and when there is a connection, I want to sync the app. How can I have it show the `'internet disconnected'` message on disconnecting the internet? Is reaction the correct mechanism to use here or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've probably figured out, MobX can only react to properties that are explicitly marked as `@observable`, and window properties are... not that.

As an alternative, [online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events) might be of interest here.

```
const {observable, autorun} = mobx

class NetStore {
  @observable isOnline = window.navigator.onLine

  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('online', () => this.isOnline = true)
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => this.isOnline = false)

    autorun(() => {
      // Log the online status whenever this.isOnline changes
      console.log(`Online status: ${this.isOnline}`)
    })
  }
}
```